# Best way to store large number of outputs from numerical simulations

Tags: c++, linux, database

I am developing an application in C++ where I will run a numerical simulation and somehow store the simulation results. Each simulation point will be associated with many fields (i.e. floating point numbers), and each field has to be stored with many decimals.

So far, I am writing the data to a simple text file (one row per simulation point). In principle this works, but the number of columns in the file is very large due to the large number of fields and the large number of decimals for each field. Sometimes I wish to manually inspect the file, and the large number of columns then becomes an issue.

Is there a better way to store the data than to simply write it to a textfile? Should I perhaps split the output over several files? Should I consider writing the output to some kind of database instead, where I could probably store the fields with full precision and inspect the output in some kind of GUI application? Other suggestions are welcome! Note that the application will be running on Linux.

Comment: If it's all fixed size columns and number of columns,you could just write a binary file.

Comment: A) Packed binary. B) Packed binary + gzip.

Comment: what is the "best" way or asking for suggestions is purely opinion based. Sometimes plain text is the most convenient. If the files are too large you could split them up in smaller files.

Comment: If you decide to make your file binary instead of text, then you will probably want a [hex editor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hex_editor) to inspect the file. Some text editors also support viewing files in binary mode.

Comment: *inspect the output in some kind of GUI application?* -- That GUI application could be a  spreadsheet application, where you can hide and show columns.

Comment: @tadman Is this what you mean by packed binary? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary-coded_decimal

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Ok, that's a good point. I guess I could in principle just import the datafile into spreadsheet program, though it might be a bit slow.

Comment: It depends some on what you ultimately need to do with the results. One possibility for the text file is to use 16 decimal places in a CSV. Then the data could be easily viewable in a spreadsheet program.

Comment: No, I mean more like binary structures packed tightly together, as in no wasted space for alignment. In C++ the compiler will often introduce a bit of padding in your structures and classes for various reasons. This means you can't just dump out your struct as `char*` to a file. You need to *serialize* it properly.

Comment: @stark Ok, thanks for the suggestion. Are you suggesting something along similar lines to tadman? Do you mean that the serialization is trivial if the column size and number of columns is fixed?

Comment: @tadman Ok, thanks for the clarification! I think this is an interesting idea. It would also make it easier to import a specific simulation point into the program for further analysis.

Comment: @QuercusRobur I kinda hint at that in my "answer", but whatever file format you land on, it would be to your advantage to make sure that it's something you can incrementally append to as the simulation advances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a *bit* orthogonal, but based on how context-dependant any answer to your question has to be, I think this is appropriate here.

Considering your hesitation, I would strongly recommend adding a layer of indirection so that you can easily support various formats and/or stuff like having a dedicated file output thread interchangeably.

Something along those lines should do:

```cpp
struct StepData {
  //...
};

class DataSink {
public:
  virtual ~DataSink () {}
  virtual void push(const StepData& data) = 0;
};

// Dumps data as binary.
class ToBinaryFileSink final : public DataSink {
  static_assert(std::is_trivially_copyable_v<StepData>, "Step data cannot be memcpyed");
  std::ofstream _file;
public:  
  ToBinaryFileSink(const std::string& filename) 
    : _file(filename, std::ios::binary) {
     // presumably write some interesting header.
   }

  ~ToBinaryFileSink() {
     // presumably write some interesting footer.
  }

  void push(const StepData& data) override {
    _file.write(&data, sizeof(data));
  }
}
```

A few notes:

- The `final` keyword. It's useful here to remove the virtual call overhead when using the sink subclasses directly, or when the compiler uses devirtualization.
- `DataSink` is designed to encourage **streaming** the results as they are generated, as opposed to gathering all data and dumping it at the end of the simulation, which is something you almost certainly want regardless of the final file format.
- If you want to get fancier, you can also template `DataSink` on the `StepData` type, as well as templating a simulation run on the sink type.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I think this is a neat way to organize things. In the end, I might write the data both as a plain text file (for easy inspection e.g. in a spreadsheet program) and in a binary format (to facilitate importing a specific simulation point and storing it with full precision).

Comment: If you have a serializer/deserializer pair, as you'd need to work with that data, you can always write a quick command-line tool to dump out a text version of your binary data. This is super handy not just when debugging, but when working with your app and trying to integrate it into other workflows.

Comment: Seconding what @tadman is recommending. Do as little as possible within the simulation app itself (you want it to run as fast as possible after all). Outputing once and then converting as needed after the fact is generaly preferable.